# Navigation content wrapping using Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, tailwind-css

Hey guys my problem is visible in the picture. I want my navigation items to stay on a single line, not break into 2. What I've tried doesn't work. Any ideas?

[Here is the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poV19.png)

```
    <ul className="md:flex hidden justify-between items-center h-20 pb-5 duration-500">
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize ">
        <CustomLink to="/">HOME</CustomLink>
      </li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize ">
        <CustomLink to="/Uberuns">ÜBER UNS</CustomLink>
      </li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize pr-2">
        <CustomLink to="/Service">SERVICE</CustomLink>
      </li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize pr-6">
        <CustomLink to="/Beratung">BERATUNG</CustomLink>
      </li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize pr-6">
        <CustomLink to="/Referenzen">REFERENZEN</CustomLink>
      </li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize">
        <CustomLink to="/Kontakt">KONTAKT</CustomLink>
      </li>
    </ul>;
```

Comment: the image is not loading, can you upload it somewhere else and then provide the link, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whitespace-nowrap`.

```
    <ul className="md:flex hidden justify-between items-center h-20 pb-5 duration-500">
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize "><CustomLink to="/">HOME</CustomLink></li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize whitespace-nowrap"><CustomLink to="/Uberuns">ÜBER UNS</CustomLink></li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize pr-2"><CustomLink to="/Service">SERVICE</CustomLink></li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize pr-6"><CustomLink to="/Beratung">BERATUNG</CustomLink></li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize pr-6"><CustomLink to="/Referenzen">REFERENZEN</CustomLink></li>
      <li className="cursor-pointer capitalize"><CustomLink to="/Kontakt">KONTAKT</CustomLink></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is a demo:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TcAbgSgIPV?layout=horizontal